# TypeError : nil is not a symbol render :json

Tags: ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4

Here is my code

```
 def get_suppliers
    supplier= Supplier.where(:user_id=>params[:supplier][:user_id],:is_deleted => "false")
    if supplier.present?        
        render :json => {"status_code" => "200", :suppliers => supplier}
         else
        render :json => {"status_code" => "400", :suppliers => "Record not found"}  
      end       
    end
```

// supplier value

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Supplier id: 69, supplier_name: "raj", food_business_no: "", mobile: "9154441222", work_phone: "9155551222 ", email_id: "raj@aol.in", date: "2014-11-18", other_information: "--", street_name: "VGP ", image_user_id: 1140, province: "", city: "", pincode: " ", state: "Australian capital teritory", country: "Australia", user_id: 42, supplier_user_id: 4, is_deleted: false, deleted_at: nil, created_at: "2014-11-18 09:26:56", updated_at: "2014-11-18 09:26:56">, #<Supplier id: 72, supplier_name: "tester", food_business_no: "", mobile: "3548621102", work_phone: "3549928500 ", email_id: "tester@asdol.in", date: "2014-11-21", other_information: "--", street_name: "sdf ", image_user_id: 1166, province: "", city: "", pincode: " ", state: "Australian capital teritory", country: "Australia", user_id: 42, supplier_user_id: 5, is_deleted: false, deleted_at: nil, created_at: "2014-11-21 11:49:15", updated_at: "2014-11-21 11:49:15">, #<Supplier id: 74, supplier_name: "bobby", food_business_no: "", mobile: "9792626506", work_phone: "9852525252 ", email_id: "bobby@aol.com", date: "2014-11-27", other_information: "--", street_name: "VIP ", image_user_id: 1175, province: "", city: "", pincode: " ", state: "Australian capital teritory", country: "Australia", user_id: 42, supplier_user_id: 7, is_deleted: false, deleted_at: nil, created_at: "2014-11-27 06:49:25", updated_at: "2014-11-27 06:49:25">]
```

I am getting `TypeError : nil is not a symbol`  on this line

```
render :json => {"status_code" => "200", :suppliers => supplier}
```

in my production server , but works well in my localhost , development server.

Here is log :

```
I, [2014-12-13T07:32:18.950505 #8580]  INFO -- : Started POST "/get_suppliers" for 182.73.35.250 at 2014-12-13 07:32:18 +0000
I, [2014-12-13T07:32:18.951363 #8580]  INFO -- : Processing by SuppliersController#get_suppliers as */*
I, [2014-12-13T07:32:18.951436 #8580]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"access_token"=>"xxxxxx", "supplier"=>{"user_id"=>"42"}}
I, [2014-12-13T07:32:18.954972 #8580]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms
F, [2014-12-13T07:32:18.956617 #8580] FATAL -- : 
TypeError (nil is not a symbol):
  app/controllers/suppliers_controller.rb:15:in `get_suppliers'
```

Comment: its a wild guess, but can you try `render :json => {:status_code => "200", :suppliers => supplier.to_json}`

Comment: @shivam  not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue , this caused because of there is no primary key in the table ,

This worked after i add primary key in the model

```
class Supplier < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.primary_key = 'id'
   ......
   .... 
end
```

Comment: Should you really need to have this on the model itself? If you created the model with the Rails generator this wouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

`supplier` is a local variable object. Kindly changes your code 
Like

```
def get_suppliers
@supplier= Supplier.where(:user_id=>params[:supplier][:user_id],:is_deleted => "false")
if @supplier.present?        
    render :json => {"status_code" => "200", :suppliers => @supplier}
     else
    render :json => {"status_code" => "400", :suppliers => "Record not found"}  
  end       
end
```

Sorry my Bad

Well may be you need to change`status_code` to `:status`